# Correct preposition - a view to

Tags: prepositions

Is the sentence correct? Does it sound natural?

The view from the room's window was **to** the garages.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are *naming* the specific thing you can see then it is "a view *of*" that thing. The correct expression would be:

> The view from the room's window was **of** the garages.

Or perhaps a more natural expression might be:

> The room had a view of the garages from the window.

We use "a view *to*..." when referring to a *direction*, for example:

> A view to the west.

Also, we use "a view to" when speaking about looking *forward to the future*, for example:

> I bought a bicycle with a view to cycling to work.